# Ms Access cannot get value from record set

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on an Access application (2007) in which there is an invocation of a stored procedure (SQL-Server 2012) which is supposed to return a simple result, a one column table with two records.

When executing the procedure within the Server Management Studio, it shows a result as follows:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| One_Sticker                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| This is the first record of the result                   |
| This is the second record of the result                  |
| This is the third and last record of the result          |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

In my Access code I have (Note: I know this is to be done within a loop, but the following is for debugging purposes only):

```
             Set RS = ADOCmd.Execute


             Set blabla = RS.NextRecordset      ' Get 1st record
     <BP-1>  Dummy_Variable = 1

             Set blabla = RS.NextRecordset      ' Get 2nd record
     <BP-2>  Dummy_Variable = 1

             Set blabla = RS.NextRecordset      ' Get 3rd record
     <BP-3>  Dummy_Variable = 1

             Set blabla = RS.NextRecordset      ' No more data.
     <BP-4>  Dummy_Variable = 1
```

[ means Breakpoint at this line]

I'm running this with a watch at `blabla` to see what is being assigned to it every step.

When looking at the watch on BPs 1, 2 and 3, `blabla` has a value while at BP 4 it is empty. This implies to me that the requred 3 records are indeed being returned.
The problem is the the `Fields` entry within `blabla` has nothing (and hence `blabla.Fields("One_Sticker").Value` is unknown).
How can i get the value of the One_Sticher field at blabla?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any useful suggestion.

Comment: What do to u expect in BP4? What values you are getting in `blabla` for the first 3 statements?

Comment: The 4 BPs were set just to make sure that we not only get data records, but we get the number of records we expect (3 in this case). At the 4th BP we observe that there is no data as it should be. So, we do get data records in the correct number, but we have problems extracting the **VALUE** from each record (as stated, `blabla.Fields("One_Sticker").Value` does not appear to be the correct way of doing it).

Comment: tried using `blabla.Fields.Item(0)` ?

Comment: still same error

Answer (score 0):

In Access, I would normally:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT field FROM table WHERE somecriteria ORDER BY field;")
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
For x = 1 to 3
    blabla = rs!One_Sticker
    Debug.Print blabla
    rs.MoveNext
Next
End If
```